# Finishing AWS authentication flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

TLDR
I am looking for somewhere to send cognito JWT's from the backend to verify the user's status.

---

I currently have a react app, with a serverless apollo api, and dynamodb database, all running locally.

- The react client uses aws-amplify to register, sign-in etc with
  aws-cognito - returning access, id and refresh tokens.
- Users can also sign in with facebook and google,
  amplify.Auth.federatedSignIn which returns the cognito identity
  credentials.
- The tokens are then passed to the backend, where they are verified.

So far I cannot find where to send the tokens from the backend, to verify that the user is signed in to cognito.
I have scoured the docs but TBH that has left me more confused.

As far as I can understand, in production API Gateway, or AppSync can intecept the tokens between the front and backend, but since I have verified tokens at the backend currently is there an endpoint or SDK method I can hit with tokens/ access keys etc to check the users status?

Feel free to tell me if I'm going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to verify that a token is valid and unexpired, with the JavaScript SDK use

```
const cognitoServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});
await cognitoServiceProvider.getUser({
        AccessToken: accessToken
    }).promise();
```

This will throw an error if the token is not valid.

If you are using a different SDK, find the equivalent call.

Comment: Hi Joey, this works great for validating the token, but after I sign the user out using amplify from the client, the access token is still valid when using the getUser method.

Is this the expected behaviour i.e. that the access token is valid until it's expiration once created?
Is there a method to invalidate the token when a user signs out of cognito?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior. The only way to invalidate the JWT is to wait for the expiration period. Usually “signing out” just means deleting the token from local storage.